# Windows, PyCharm: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 32-bit Oracle Client library

Tags: python, oracle, pycharm

I need help, I'm getting this error all the time.
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/Anonimizacija/OracleConnect.py", line 3, in 
con = cx_Oracle.connect("andjela", "andjela", "localhost/xe")
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 32-bit Oracle Client library: "C:\app\DELL\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oci.dll is not the correct architecture". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help
'''
I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 32-bit python but a 64-bit Oracle database.

The best thing would be install a 64-bit Python.

Or you could upgrade to cx_Oracle to 8, download a 32-bit Oracle Instant Client and unzip it, and then pass the Instant Client directory to cx_Oracle 8's `init_oracle_client()`:

```
import cx_Oracle
import sys

try:
    cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"C:\oracle\instantclient_19_6")
except Exception as err:
    print("Whoops!")
    print(err);
    sys.exit(1);
```

See the cx_Oracle doc [Using cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client() to set the Oracle Client directory](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#using-cx-oracle-init-oracle-client-to-set-the-oracle-client-directory).

With this function you do not need to add the Instant Client directory to PATH (which might impact Oracle XE database use).